# Need authoritative source for historic Bitcoin conversion prices from all exchanges

Tags: exchanges, api, exchange-rate, historical-trade-data

What are the authoritative sources for historic Bitcoin prices?

Ideally this will be an API for all major exchanges.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All historical data from any exchange available at [Bitcoin Charts: Markets API](https://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/)

> **Historic Trade Data**
>
> Trade data is available as CSV, delayed by approx. 15 minutes. It will return the 2000 most recent trades.
>   Format:
>
> `https://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv?symbol=SYMBOL[&start=UNIXTIME]`
>
> Returns CSV with columns: `unixtime,price,amount`
>
> **Example**
>
> Latest *Kraken EUR* trades:
>   https://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv?symbol=krakenEUR

Comment: Thats a good starting point, but I don't know how "authoritative" it is since it seems to be a 3rd party.  I wonder how they collect the information in the first place.  Do you know if they simply screen-scrape the info?

Comment: @makerofthings7, BitcoinCharts is the main markets watch website, operator Nils Schneider aka tcatm - Bitcoin developer, owner of BitcoinWatch, creator and owner of BitcoinCharts, GPU mining software and JS web interface - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/People . It as authoritative as it gets in Bitcoin community. Every exchange listed on this site upload its historical data on the website - http://bitcoincharts.com/about/exchanges/

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of that linked google docs spreadsheet are instructions to download data from Mt Gox and many other Exchanges. Namely:

- Go to this link: http://bitcoincharts.com/charts/mtgoxUSD#tgSzm1g10zm2g25zv
- Click load raw data

This raw data only maintains daily prices.  This is probably the closing price for the day, but I can't be sure of that.

I'm not sure how bitcoin charts actually collects this information from the other providers.  I hope other

Answer (score 3):

Many API endpoints included OHLC data from various exchanges can be found on

- [cryptowatch](https://cryptowat.ch/docs/api)
- [cryptocompare](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#introduction)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a one-stop shop for lots of different exchanges/markets, Coinigy provides [historical crypto data](http://coinigy.com/bitcoin-data/). It's not free but probably one of the better sources.